# Angular exposed component methods

Tags: angular, autocomplete, phpstorm

I've got component that has public methods which may be used by parent component, however these methods are not highlighted by PhpStorm (like when you are using class with interface).

Is there a way to explicitly declare component's methods which can be used so that PhpStorm with Angular language service would strengthen them(in the suggested list of options)? (needed for easiness of team development and faster coding).

Just in case, I'm talking about autocomplete list of methods and properties (when you type something then `.` and PhpStorm suggests available options bold and white)

Comment: This should work. Please post the code of your corresponding typescript classes (minimal sample).

Comment: Just realized the mistake. It was `@ViewChild('add') public addPopup` thus not having any interface no suggestions could be

Comment: so, is it solved now?